# Generalized Eigenvectors Lemma from Artin's "Algebra"

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, generalized-eigenvector

This is from Artin's "Algebra" (2nd Edition), Proposition 4.7.1 and Lemma 4.7.2..

Let $x$ be a generalized eigenvector of a linear operator $T$, with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and exponent $d$. For $j\geq0$, let $u_{j}=(T-\lambda)^{j}x$, $B=(u_{0},...,u_{d-1})$ and $z$ be a nontrivial linear combination of $B$. Then $z$ is a generalized eigenvector <strike>with eigenvalue $\require{cancel} \cancel{\lambda}$ and exponent $\require{cancel} \cancel{d-j}$</strike> . (Edited)

I'm having trouble understanding some of the steps in the proof of the lemma. Firstly, it is claimed that for a linear combination $y=c_{j}u_{j}+\ ... \ +c_{d-1}u_{d-1}$ with  $j\leq d-1$ and $c_{j}\neq0$, $$(T-\lambda)^{d-j-1}y=c_{j}u_{d-1}.$$

By the way it is written I believe the author meant simply to ensure that $y$ is a nontrivial linear combination of the elements of $B$ and that the $j$-th element wouldn't be repeated, this might be where I am mistaken. That would yield,
$$\begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned} (T-\lambda)^{d-j-1}y&=c_{j}(T-\lambda)^{d-j-1}u_{j}+\sum_{i=0;i\neq j}^{d-1}c_{i}(T-\lambda)^{d-j-1}u_{i} \\
&=c_{j}(T-\lambda)^{d-1}x \ + \sum_{i=0;i\neq j}^{d-1}c_{i}(T-\lambda)^{d+i-j-1}x \\
&=c_{j}u_{d-1} \ + \sum_{i=0;i\neq j}^{d-1}c_{i}(T-\lambda)^{d+i-j-1}x. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}$$

In this last equation I don't see how the terms on the right add up to $0$ or how they are all $0$ for any $j\leq d-1$. The next step of the proof claims the following,
$$(T-\lambda)^{d-j}y=0.$$
Which from the previous equations becomes,
$$\begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned} 
(T-\lambda)^{d-j}y&=c_{j}(T-\lambda)^{d}x \ + \sum_{i=0;i\neq j}^{d-1}c_{i}(T-\lambda)^{d+i-j}x \\
&=0 \ + \sum_{i=0;i\neq j}^{d-1}c_{i}(T-\lambda)^{d+i-j}x. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}$$

And I have essentially the same question here. What I can think of is, in both cases, splitting the operator,
$$\sum_{i=0;i\neq j}^{d-1}c_{i}(T-\lambda)^{d+i-j-1}x=\sum_{i=0;i\neq j}^{d-1}c_{i}(T-\lambda)^{i-j-1}(T-\lambda)^{d}x,$$ and similarly, $$\sum_{i=0;i\neq j}^{d-1}c_{i}(T-\lambda)^{d+i-j}x=\sum_{i=0;i\neq j}^{d-1}c_{i}(T-\lambda)^{i-j}(T-\lambda)^{d}x.$$

This would lead me to the answer, however I'm unsure about the details regarding invertibility, or even one sided inverses, of the operator $(T-\lambda)$ as some of the powers would be negative.

Any explanations or hints regarding theorems or lemmas from linear algebra that I might be forgetting will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've written the statement of the lemma wrong in part of the statement and in your work.

Note that $y = c_j u_j + \cdots + c_{d-1} u_{d-1}$ with $c_j \ne 0$. In particular, there are no terms involving $u_1, \ldots, u_{j-1}$.

Therefore your sums should be $\sum_{i = j+1}^{d-1}$. Then $i-j > i-j-1 \ge 0$ so there are no negative exponents in the end of your proof attempt.

Comment: I believe I identified the mistake and edited accordingly. Regarding the proof of the lemma, with the help of your answer I understand that I misunderstood how $y$ was defined and can now see how the result is obtained in the sums. Lastly, regarding $z$ in the proof of the proposition for any arbitrary, nontrivial linear combination of $B$ different exponents would be required for different linear combinations but, for instance, for $w=u_{0}+ ... + u_{d-1}$ the exponent would be $d$ and the different exponents needed $p$, depending on the combination would be $1\leq p \leq d$, correct? Thanks.